# There is no build provider registered for the extension '.rss'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to make a .rss file in my ASP.NET application work like a .ashx and although I did everything I was supposed to, I am still getting this error:

There is no build provider registered for the extension '.rss'. You can register one in the  section in machine.config or web.config. Make sure is has a BuildProviderAppliesToAttribute attribute which includes the value 'Web' or 'All'.

There IS a build provider registered!

```
<buildProviders>
  <add extension="*.rss" type="System.Web.Compilation.WebHandlerBuildProvider"/>
</buildProviders>

<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.rss"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.rss" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory"/>
  ...
```

I also added .rss in the IIS config. What is left to do?! Using ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 2):

In the `extension` attribute, remove the asterisk:

```
<add extension=".rss" type="System.Web.Compilation.WebHandlerBuildProvider"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Build providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildprovider.aspx) are used to generate source code at runtime.  Are you sure you mean to generate source code for rss files?  One thing I can say with a decent amount of certainty is [there appears to be no WebHandlerBuildProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.aspx).

Also, have you seen the [RSS Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETRSSToolkit)?

Comment: "read this" link has been broken - if you can track down another, or copy and paste some of the helpful parts inline (if allowed) that would be a great help.